# send GET http request from iphone to local web server

Tags: iphone, httpwebrequest

Hi im working on a application that gives you information  about your current location(Country, town,street) so I want to send the town and street to a local web server ! i found a code that technically works when i use this URL :

```
@"http://localhost:8888/jml/save.php?town=California&street=whatever"
```

But what i want is to get the values from a labels (townText/ streetText) and at this point nothing seems to happing ?!!

this is the code :

```
if (![self.townText.text isEqualToString:@""] && ![self.streetText.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat**:@"http://localhost:8888/jml/save.php?town=%@&street=%@",self.townText.text,streetText.txt**]];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

So please i need your help :) and thank you !

Comment: You also have introduced a memory leak by not releasing the variable `url`. You can safely release this variable after you have created the `urlRequest` object.

Comment: @Sam: he is probably using ARC.

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhone isn't running the webserver itself - it's running on your development machine. Try switching "localhost" for your machine's IP address, and make sure that it's reachable from whatever network your development phone is on.

In addition - make sure that you're escaping the fields you're putting in the URL. If they contain characters that are not valid in a URL, your request will fail. You can escape your URL like so:

```
NSString* myURLString = [NSString
                         stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/jml/save.php?town=%@&street=%@", self.townText.text, self.streetText.text];
myURLString = [myURLString   
               stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Also: I'm assuming that those double-asterisks in your code sample are for illustration only, as that's not valid Obj-C syntax. You're also referencing a member (`streetText.txt`) that doesn't exist - you may have mistyped `streetText.text`.

Comment: thank you Peter it works , my problem is that i'm not escaping the fields !! so i fix it now thanks to you.

 thank you again ;)

Comment: how can i add this notification to my app !

http://help.agilebits.com/1Password_touch/images/tutorials/manual_sync/WiFi_sync_background.png

Comment: actually i've done with these statment :                                                                       UIApplication* app2 = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; 
    app2.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; 
    
    app2.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;