# NSURLRequest Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios

i am develop the iOS web app using php and mysql database and my problem is nsurl request get to values to php file not response and not working but,i am printing in command prompt url and copy the url paste and go to browser sucessfully updated.but, not updated and no response nsurl request what's wrong in my code?can any one help me!

```
            NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.20:90/inkfreakz/update.php?fname=%@&lname=%@&gender=%@&dob=%@&uname=%@&email=%@&city=%@&zcode=%@&state=%@&count=%@&tattoo=%@&aboutme=%@&id=%@",txt_first.text,txt_last.text,txt_gender.text,txt_birth.text,txt_user.text,txt_email.text,txt_city.text,txt_zip.text,txt_state.text,txt_country.text,txt_tatoo.text,txt_about.text,[results objectAtIndex:13]]];
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.20:90/inkfreakz/update.php?fname=%@&lname=%@&gender=%@&dob=%@&uname=%@&email=%@&city=%@&zcode=%@&state=%@&count=%@&tattoo=%@&aboutme=%@&id=%@",txt_first.text,txt_last.text,txt_gender.text,txt_birth.text,txt_user.text,txt_email.text,txt_city.text,txt_zip.text,txt_state.text,txt_country.text,txt_tatoo.text,txt_about.text,[results objectAtIndex:14]]);

            NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:5];

            NSData *urlData;
            NSURLResponse *response;
            urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
            NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            if(newStr.length==0)
            {
                lbl_status.text=@"Can't Communicate with Server!";
                lbl_status.hidden=NO;
                [my_scroll_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];
            }
            else {
                lbl_status.text=newStr;
                lbl_status.hidden=NO;
                [my_scroll_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How about using the `error:` parameter (instead of passing nil) to see if it's reporting an error?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9930735/1344459

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `– stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` to build your URL, since it is likely it needs some escaping:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.20:90/inkfreakz/update.php?fname=%@&lname=%@&gender=%@&dob=%@&uname=%@&email=%@&city=%@&zcode=%@&state=%@&count=%@&tattoo=%@&aboutme=%@&id=%@",txt_first.text,txt_last.text,txt_gender.text,txt_birth.text,txt_user.text,txt_email.text,txt_city.text,txt_zip.text,txt_state.text,txt_country.text,txt_tatoo.text,txt_about.text,[results objectAtIndex:13];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try code below;

```
NSString *urlString = [@"your url addres as string" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
```

if your url has spaces this will work.. Or you should look NSString functions.